# COUNT and SUM at the same time after removing duplicate rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL and I can't figure out a query for doing a COUNT and a SUM of two different columns. Basically I'm looking for something like a `SUM(hits DISTINCT record_id)`

The table:

```
status      record_id      hits     
     0            123         1
     0            123         1
     0            124         1
     0            125         1
     0            126         0
     1            123         0
     1            124         0
     1            125         1
     1            125         1
```

The desired result:

```
status   unique_records_count  hits_sum
     0                      4         3
     1                      3         1
```

Doing a

```
SELECT status, COUNT(DISTINCT record_id), SUM(hits)
FROM table
GROUP BY status
```

returns

```
status   unique_records_count  hits_sum
     0                      4         4
     1                      3         2
```

Comment: does hits depend on status and record_id or is ist possible that there are two records with same status and record_id but different hit? your query returns an all database system the same result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fb8b8/1

Answer (score 6):

```
Select A.status,count (A.record_id),sum(A.hits)
from 
(Select distinct status,record_id,hits from YourTable) A
group by A.status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH distinct_records (status, record_id, hits) (
    SELECT max(status, record_id, hits 
      FROM your_table
  GROUP BY status, record_id, hits -- group by faster than distinct
)
SELECT status, count(record_id), sum(hits) from distinct_records;
```

JP Chauhan's answer should give you the right answer too.  Either way you are dealing with a subquery.  it is worth considering that group by is often faster than distinct depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this. JP Chauhan's solution also worked well with inner joins in my subquery to sum the count of a field by date. I found that my alias had an issue and had to fix that, but other wise works perfect.

```
select a.ptype, a.mydate, sum(a.pcount) as ProvCount
from 
   (select bkcat."Pe" ptype
         , count (distinct a.id) as pcount
         , to_char(a.upload_date,'mm/yyyy') as MYDate
    from teuplas a   
    inner join catalog as bkcat 
        on a.id = bkcat.upload_id
    where a.upload_date between '2015/05/28' and '2015/06/02'  
      and bkcat."Pe" = '...'
    group by a.upload_date, bkcat."Pe"
           , to_char(a.upload_date,'mm/dd/yyyy')
    -- order by a.upload_date desc
    -- limit 2000
    -- upload_date, (to_char(date_trunc('month',a.upload_date),'mm') 
    --             ||'/'
    --             ||to_char(date_trunc('year',a.upload_date),'yy')) 
    --                         as "Upload_Month/Year",
   ) as a
group by ptype, a.mydate
```

Comment: we edited the formatting of the code. If you prefer the old formatting, you can rollback the change.